Columns to rows in one scan and one query
With an example table (> 20M rows) like this :
CREATE TABLE T (
  D DATE,
  V INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2024-07-01', 1), ('2024-07-02', 2), ('2024-07-02', 3);

I have an existing query that take about 5s :
SELECT D, 'SUM', SUM(V)
FROM T
GROUP BY D
UNION
SELECT D, 'AVG', AVG(V)
FROM T
GROUP BY D
ORDER BY 1;

And needed output :



Column A
Column B
Column B




2024-07-01
SUM
1.0


2024-07-01
AVG
1.0


2024-07-02
SUM
5.0


2024-07-02
AVG
2.5



To avoid multiple scan I rewrite like this (about 1 s) :
SELECT D, SUM(V), AVG(V)
FROM T
GROUP BY D;

I need to keep output, can only do it in one query, so I tried a common table expression :
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT D, SUM(V) AS S, AVG(V) AS A
  FROM T
  GROUP BY D
)
SELECT D, 'SUM', S
FROM CTE
UNION
SELECT D, 'AVG', A
FROM CTE
ORDER BY 1;

But table is still scan twice, and query is still in 5s :



select_type
table




PRIMARY
< derived2>


DERIVED
T


UNION
< derived4>


DERIVED
T


UNION RESULT
<union1,3>



Is there an option to do it in one query and only one scan ?
EDIT:
Found a solution with json but I don't like it :
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT D, JSON_ARRAY(SUM(V), AVG(V)) AS data
    FROM T
    GROUP BY D
)
SELECT
  c.D,
  CASE WHEN JT.Id = 1 THEN 'SUM'
       WHEN JT.Id = 2 THEN 'AVG'
  END AS F,
  JT.N
FROM CTE c,
JSON_TABLE(c.data, '$[*]'
  COLUMNS(
    Id for ordinality,
    N FLOAT PATH '$[0]'
  )
) AS JT;


Do you have an index on date? Please add explain plan for both queries.

@P.Salmon This query is an exemple. The real query is more complex and index are ok

Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? You tagged both in your question, but these are not the same product, and they are increasingly incompatible with each other. Please run SELECT VERSION(); and add the result to your post.

@BillKarwin mariadb 10.6.18

did you try a subquery instead of a cte?  if that doesn't work, maybe a subquery with an extra level of nesting?

@ysth No, I don't see how to do it

if you are seeing your base query go from 5s to 1s removing the union, you likely will see some improvement just from changing union to union all.  union defaults to union distinct which can be a performance hit

@ysth In fact I have 5 UNION and each one takes 1 second. I want to avoid multiscan of a big table. UNION ALL don't help

I would use a subquery for this:
select D, rowtype, case rowtype when 'SUM' then sum_v else avg_v end value
from (
    select D, sum(V) sum_v, avg(V) avg_v
    from T
    group by D
) sum_or_avg
join (select 'SUM' rowtype union all select 'AVG') rowtype
order by D, rowtype desc

